# Determine if variable is the smallest out of a set of variables in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, variables

community!
I would like to ask if there is any easy way to determine if a variable is has the smallest value out of a set of different variables.

An example:

```
is_smallest($var, $foo, $bing, $bong, $bung);
```

Should return 'true' when $var is smaller than $foo *and* $bing *and* $bong *and* $bung, and false when it is bigger than one of these values.

Is there any builtin function in the PHP-Processor which makes this task easy or is it neccessary to create your own algorithm? If so, how to handle an undefined amound of parameters in PHP?

I'm looking forward to your answers :)

With kind regards,

Sebastian A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `min` function:

```
if($var == min($var, $foo, $bing, $bong, $bung))
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I think that should do the job. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Femaref answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10397309/50079), [`min`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) already does most of the work needed, and with a better syntax too -- with a hypothetical `is_smallest` it's not at all clear *which* argument we are testing for smallestness.

Another option closer to the spirit of `is_smallest` you might like to consider is

```
function min_index() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return array_search(min($args), $args);
}

if (min_index($a, $b, $c, $d) == 0) {
    // 0: $a is smallest, 1: $b is smallest, etc
}
```